# How to link/add custom CSS to bootstrap theme in Drupal 8

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I am new to Drupal 8 and want to link a custom CSS file in my bootstrap subtheme. There is no way to link the CSS file in the theme.info.yml file. however, I was able to link my custom CSS in theme.info in Drupal 7. Guide me on how to add custom CSS in the Drupal 8 bootstrap subtheme.

Comment: Why would you want to add the custom css in bootstrap main theme ?

Comment: To implement my own design.

Comment: @ShakilAhmad You can definitely implement your own design in a sub theme; sub themes can override every aspect of the main theme.  A subtheme is a way of protecting your changes when the main theme is updated; it doesn't limit your design in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is designed for you to add extra CSS to a subtheme, not the main theme.

The Bootstrap documentation says this:

> Warning You should never modify any theme or sub-theme that is
>   packaged and released from Drupal.org, such as Drupal Bootstrap. If
>   you do, all changes you have made will be lost once that theme is
>   updated. Instead, you should create a subtheme from one of the
>   provided starterkits (this is considered a best practice). Once you've
>   done that, you can override CSS, templates, and theme processing.

Bootstrap even provides starter kits so you can easily make the theme yourself, plus [step-by-step documentation](https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21Sub-Theming.md/group/sub_theming/8).

Answer (score 1):

Don't do on main theme instead create a sub-theme and change what you like. Here are some links that can help you set up Bootstrap sub-theme

- https://www.webfoobar.com/node/9
- https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21Sub-Theming.md/group/sub_theming/8

You can use either SASS or LESS starterkit. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, I know that editing main theme is not good practice. but I just want to know how.

Comment: Please follow instruction mention here - https://www.webfoobar.com/node/9

Comment: I always convert scss to css extension using gulp and the converted file save inside the css folder (themes\custome_theme\css\style.css). So, I can put reference on custom_theme.libraries.yml point to the style.css file. All my custom scss files keep under the "scss" folders.  My folder structure of custom .scss files  themes\custom_theme\scss\custome_theme\\*.scss (files).

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not a good idea to add your own CSS to a base-theme, you need to add it to `bootstrap.libraries.yml`